# Copying data from excel into access with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, import

Im trying to update an Access database with new code to add to one aggregate list of scan entries. The macro needs to open the access file, copy the range from excel and paste it at the bottom of the database to add to the already existing records. Then save the access .accdb file and then close. Any tips particularly on the copying and pasting data portion?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Excel's "record macro" function can be useful in finding a place to start.

Comment: Is there a way to record lines of VBA code when you start in excel and move to doing things in access? I've tried this, and couldn't get the code to record.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ACE.OLEDB`. Create an SQL INSERT STATEMENT. Code would look something like below:

```
    Sub Test()
        accessFilePath = "C:\someDB.accdb"
        Call ExecuteSQLCmd("INSERT INTO `" & accessFilePath & "`.`Table` (col1,col2,col3) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM [Sheet1$]", accessFilePath)
     End Sub

   Sub ExecuteSQLCmd(cmd As String, accessFilePath as String )

        Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim sql As String

        Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
        cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFilePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

        If Not (cnn Is Nothing) Then
            'Execute Sql
            cnn.Execute (cmd)
            'Close
            cnn.Close
        End If
        Set cnn = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: How do I go about making sure ADO.OLEBD is being used?

Comment: Sorry typo - meant the ACE.OLEDB provider. See the code above

Comment: Okay, scratch that. its returning an error that says: "the Microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Sheet1'$'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Comment: im fairly new to Access. So far im just testing on an emtpy .accdb file that only has an empty Table1. Is this right?

Comment: okay.. i made a query. new error: "Query must have at least one destination field"...?